# Error establishing a database connection due to curl_setopt

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

I have a Virtual Server (1 CPU 1020 MB RAM), with Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and Apache2, PHP5.5, Mysql, and four web projects inside with a low number of users. It has worked like a charm last year. But suddenly, when I try to access any of those projects, I see this error on the browser:

> Error establishing a connection to the database

I have solved it by restarting mysql:

```
service mysql restart
```

but the error comes again after a while. Checking log files I've found in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

> [Tue Aug 05 09:04:45.607024 2014] [:error] [pid 8545] [client ipAddress] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in /webDir/project/wp-content/themes/custom/js/aPhpFile.php on line 56, referer: webDomain

Looking at this code:

```
$op = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
  CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle all encodings
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'sharrre', // who am i
  CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5, // timeout on connect
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, // timeout on response
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 3, // stop after 10 redirects
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
);
$ch = curl_init();

$op[CURLOPT_URL] = $encUrl;  
curl_setopt_array($ch, $op);
```

and this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121, I can see why this error is thrown.

I just disabled `open_basedir` (`safe_mode` is also disabled) and restarted the server.

Again I see this error which appears and disappears. But now there are no new errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Even I've tried:

```
//Show today logs
grep -r "Aug\s05" /var/log
```

But the only messages are in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Any idea of what can be happening and how to solve it?

Comment: When the error occurs, is it possible to connect to your MySQL-Server from your shell?

Comment: @etagenklo - Yes, it is possible by `mysql -u root -p`.

Comment: Is it also possible with the credentials your script is using?

Comment: @etagenklo - The script is using `root` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it is not a `curl_setopt` issue. It was just an error caused by a PHP configuration file ([wordpress.stackexchange.com answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22756/error-establishing-a-database-connection-intermittent-error-on-godaddy/156888#156888)).